# Web.py db.update() - passing a dictionary as argument of where AND as values list

Tags: python, database, dictionary, sql-update, web.py

I have a Dict containing some data I want to update in db, my dict is like:

```
user[column_name] = value
>>> user
{'id': 2, 'name': 'Carlo', city='333'}
```

and have a variable number of keys (depending on how many fields the user fills), and the table contains more columns than the values I want to update.

What I'm trying to do is this:

```
>>> db.update('users', where="id=$id", **user)
0.0 (19): UPDATE users SET id = 2, name = 'Carlo', city='333' WHERE id=<built-in function id>
0L
```

but the update query is wrong, what I want to obtain is something like:

```
UPDATE users SET name='Carlo', city='333' WHERE id='2'
```

There is a way to pass a dictionary in the db.update() function using a key/value as WHERE clause and the other key/value pairs as SET parameters?

the web.py documentation refer to the db.select() instructions but it's not clear at all to me..

Thanks for any help!

Federico

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because id is a build in function, so you have to define it in vars:

```
db.update('users', where="id=$id", vars={'id': user['id']}, **user)
```

If you really don't want id=2 exists in update set, then you can do:

```
uid = user.pop('id')
db.update('users', where="id=$id", vars={'id': uid}, **user)
```

but remember to set it back if you still need it in user

Or just list every thing you want like this:

```
db.update('users', where="id=$id", vars={'id': uid}, name=user['name'], city=user['city'])
```

So vars will be used in where. All other named paramenter, except where, vars, _test will be in set